# How to find the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{48s+36}{s(6s^2+11s+6)}$?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

How to find the inverse laplace transform of this function?
 $$F(s) = \displaystyle \frac{48s+36}{s(6s^2+11s+6)}.$$
It has been hard to break down the denominator part.  Any help from you guys would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried separating using partial fractions? $\frac{48s+36}{s(6s^2+11s+6)} = \frac{A}{s} + \frac{Bs+C}{6s^2+11s^6}$.

Comment: This is the same question as your previous question. Don't circumvent closures by reposting the problem. You should edit your previous question to get it reopened. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) for more details on how to improve your question.

Comment: I think you have no idea about the question and now i have got my answer and a mathematical question doesn't require much detail, like my question those who know about it have given me the answer. The same previous question was closed by some featherbrains. Just dont be like them

Comment: I think the question has been posed clearly here, and would suggest deleting the other posting, then coming back here to attempt to reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned} F(s) &= \displaystyle \frac{48s+36}{s(6s^2+11s+6)}\\ &= \frac{8s+6}{s(s-\alpha-i\beta)(s-\alpha+i\beta)}, \quad \textrm{where } \alpha=-\frac{11}{12}, \textrm{ and } \beta = \frac{\sqrt{23}}{12}\\
&= \frac{8s+6}{s[(s-\alpha)^2+\beta^2]}
\end{aligned}$$

Expressing this as a  partial fraction expansion:

$$\begin{aligned} F(s) &= \frac{6}{s} - \frac{6(s-\alpha)}{(s-\alpha)^2+\beta^2}+\frac{5/2}{(s-\alpha)^2+\beta^2}\\&= \frac{6}{s} - 6\frac{s-\alpha}{(s-\alpha)^2+\beta^2}+\frac{30}{\sqrt{23}}\frac{\beta}{(s-\alpha)^2+\beta^2}\end{aligned} $$

So $$\begin{aligned}f(x)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\\&=6 - e^{-\alpha x}\left[6\cos \beta x - \frac{30}{\sqrt{23}}\sin \beta x \right]\\&= 6 - 6e^{-\frac{11}{12}x}\left[\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{23}}{12} x\right)- \frac{5}{\sqrt{23}}\sin\left( \frac{\sqrt{23}}{12}x\right)\right].\end{aligned}$$

---

$\textbf{UPDATE:}$
The second step, where we explicitly show the complex roots, is not necessary, but, by use of the quadratic formula, it is helpful to know that the roots are complex conjugates.  We could have gone straight to the now third step, by completing-the-square.  The main point is that the form we now have leads to a partial fraction expansion that is well known, and can be found in almost any table of Laplace transforms.

---

Comment: You're missing the independent variable at the end

Comment: Thanks!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the solution , but can you plz explain me the process of 2nd step , i got little confused in the denominator part of  s-a+ib ,s-a+ib

Comment: Hope that the update in the answer is helpful.  Please ask if it is still unclear.